# How do I spend less time in the for loop in this prime number sieve?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, sieve-of-eratosthenes

The implementation shown below of the sieve of Eratosthenes is very inefficient. I am not interested in finding the most efficient one; I just want to make what I've already made better.

I am aware that there are far different ways of doing this; I just implemented the sieve off the top of my head, and my problem is that I want to know what I can do to make one particular part of this particular implementation more efficient.

```py
def sieve(x):
    l = []
    for i in range(x + 1):
        l.append(i)
    l.remove(0)
    l.remove(1)
    clone = l[:]
    test = 0
    for i in l:
        while test < len(clone):
            checker = clone[test]
            if checker % i == 0 and i != checker and i < checker:
                clone.remove(checker)
            test += 1
        test = 0
    return clone
print(sieve(24))
```

If you paste the above code into http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit and step through, you'll notice that it's done finding all the primes before the 200th step; it mostly wastes it time going through the length of the outer `for` loop. The operating question is this then: **in this particular implementation, how do I reduce the time it spends in the `for` loop?** The most that I've done to make it more efficient is to replace four instances of `clone[test]` with a single assignment to `checker` (well, a single assignment per loop anyway).

Comment: If the code works and you just want improvement suggestions, it should be on Code Review instead. Note though, they'll require you to provide a `main` to show how it runs.

Comment: Can I request for this to be moved? Do I need to flag it? Will I lose my rep the rep I just gained here if I do that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it’s more efficient to *mark* elements as removed (single assignment at a known location) than to use `list.remove` (requires a search through the list and moves every element after the one being removed). Then you can filter them all out in one pass at the end. So like you’re doing already, indexes from 0 to x start out prime:

```
l = [True] * (x + 1)
```

then you mark some as not prime:

```
l[0] = False
l[1] = False
```

then you can simplify the inner loop to move forward a fixed number of elements each time:

```
for i in range(2, x + 1):
    if not l[i]:
        continue

    for j in range(i * i, x + 1, i):
        l[j] = False
```

starting at `i * i` because any smaller multiple of `i` in the form `s * i` was already covered when the loop hit `s`. This also has the advantage of involving no division operations.

Using the list of booleans indicating whether a given index is prime to make a list of primes, then:

```
return [i for i in range(x + 1) if l[i]]
```

This all hasn’t cut down on the number of iterations of the outer loop, but it should already be a lot faster, and with the simplified version maybe it’s easier to see how you could stop when `i * i` is bigger than the list, and also skip checking every even number.